# Filter with an array

Tags: mysql

I know you can search for an id from an array using id IN ($array) like

```
$ids = join(',',$galleries);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

Can this be done in reverse so there's a column of ids stored in the table and you pass it a single id as a condition in a where clause?

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET`, highly unreliable and bad performance, as soon as you need this, _immediately_ look into normalizing your database to prevent having to use this.

Comment: BTW: also [unrelated to `find`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/find/info)

Comment: OK any advice on the following I have a table of products each can contain up to 6 different number codes so I've stored them as comma separated ids 

what would be a better way of going about this?

Comment: A table `product_codes (product_id,code)`, with 6 entries, 1 for every code (see also [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [about](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) for more depth.

Comment: I have that already but I still need some way to reference the individual product to the code id

Comment: So, you need a join? `SELECT products.* FROM products JOIN product_codes ON product_codes.product_id = products.id AND product_codes.code='yourcode';`? This would be a very different question then the one you are asking now, posting a new one might be in order.

Comment: I think you may be right. I have more question that's off topic to my original question. Thanks for your advice.